# Authentication views for Laravel 5.1

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.1 has just been released, I would like to know how could I tell the AuthController to get the login & register view from a custom directory? the default is: `resources/views/auth`...

The trait *AuthenticateAndRegisterUsers* only has this:

```
trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers, RegistersUsers {
        AuthenticatesUsers::redirectPath insteadof RegistersUsers;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to overwrite the methods inherited from the trait.

Comment: Could you make an example please, how would i do that?

Comment: Check out the API docs. Those are the methods you can overwrite. http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those who is using laravel 5.2, you only need to override property value of loginView

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $view = property_exists($this, 'loginView')
                ? $this->loginView : 'auth.authenticate';
    if (view()->exists($view)) {
        return view($view);
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

so to override the login view path, you only need to do this

```
class yourUserController {

 use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

.....

protected $loginView = 'your path';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you're showing there only fills one function: it tells our trait to use the `redirectPath` from the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait rather than the one from `RegistersUsers`.

If you check inside the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait instead, you will find a `getLogin()` method. By default, this one is defined as

```
public function getLogin()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

All you have to do to get another view is then simply overwriting the function in your controller and returning another view. If you for some reason would like to load your views from a directory other than the standard `resources/Views`, you can do so by calling `View::addLocation($path)` (you'll find this defined in the `Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder` implementation of the `Illuminate\View\ViewFinderInterface`.

Also, please note that changing the auth views directory will do nothing to change the domain or similar. That is dependent on the function name (as per the definition of `Route::Controller($uri, $controller, $names=[])`. For more details on how routing works, I'd suggest just looking through `Illuminate\Routing\Router`.